# How to stop a script running in a tmux session?

Tags: bash, minecraft, tmux

I'm running a script in a tmux session.
The script would shut down upon getting ".stopwrapper" as input.

how can i send this input into the session with a script?

alternatively how can i shutdown the session itself with a script?

EDIT:

i'm starting the script with:

```
tmux new -d -n "minecraft" -s "minecraft" "sh /opt/minecraft/rtoolkit.sh"
```

Comment: Are you trying to write a script with this behavior, or are you trying to inject a string into the standard input of an already-running process?

Comment: its the later. i want to get the .stopwrapper into the input

Comment: Can you post more details on how you start the script?

Comment: added to the initial post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From https://gist.github.com/henrik/1967800:

```
tmux kill-session -t myname
```

You can also run a command with it's input from a named pipe (created using mkfifo). Check out http://www.catonmat.net/blog/bash-one-liners-explained-part-three/

Comment: is there a way for this to send sigterm or something that kills non gracefully

Answer (score 0):

```
fifo_file=/tmp/fifo_logs.$$    
mkfifo $fifo_file

awk '.stopwrapper {tmux kill-session -t myname}' $fifo_file
```

You have to make sure that you redirect the things you want to analyse into the fifo_file so awk sees it and execute the command.